# Show tooltip at the top of link button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-tooltip

I am using this jquery code to show tooltip for the linkbuttons in my master page. The tooltip is getting displayed below the link button and the problem is if the user navigates fast the menu disappears. So each time they have to come down slowly.

And is there is any way to show the tooltip at the top of the link button so that the user can navigate down quickly without having the menu items disappeared.

**Code:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery- ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).tooltip();
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    div.ui-tooltip
    {
        max-width: 100%;
        font-size: 14px;           
    }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<li><a href="#" class="pureCssMenui">Department</a>
                                    <ul class="pureCssMenum">
                                        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a   class="pureCssMenui" href="Manufacturer.aspx" title="Contains list of Manufacturers">
                                            Manufacturer</a></li>
                                        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="Food & Beverages.aspx" title="Has informations on foods type manufacturing">
                                            Food & Beverage</a></li>
                                        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="Transport.aspx" title="Has transport cost across globe">
                                            Transportation</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Okay, cool! I'd like to know what approach you want with this. My best suggestion is to use jQuery plugins which DO a much better job than doing it on your own. But if you're planning to learn how it works, I can also show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put options parameter in your tooltip().

```
$(document).tooltip({ position: { my: "bottom", at: "top" } });
```

Reference jQuery UI:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the JSFiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/2gLm5/4/

If your browser is incompatible, just use a third-party library like Bootstrap

Comment: I still see the tooltip getting displayed at the bottom.

Comment: Hi @Vicky, did you reference jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes I already added the reference and still its getting displayed below.

Comment: Check the JSfiddle I made, using exactly the code you gave me. Works fine on mine. You might be having conflicting CSS.

Comment: I saw your fiddle and its working as expected. And I am not using any css to get conflicted with this.

Comment: On second thought, your browser may not be compatible. What browser and version are you using?

Comment: Chat is disabled. I am using IE 8

Comment: one of my friend is having account and can I chat from there

Comment: I updated my Fiddle. I used Bootstrap, which works in IE8. Customizing jQuery UI tooltips seems to have issues with older versions of IE.

Comment: But is this not a default tooltip?

Comment: It is, and the default behavior is to show the tooltip at the bottom. To show it at the top, you send params to the tooltip(). You said that didn't work for you.

Comment: Anyway, this is how it works and how to do it the standard way. I'd appreciate an upvote if I helped in any way. I'm reading other people's issues with tooltips on IE8. perhaps upgrade to a newer version?